# Media query works on chrome but firefox picks up wrong resolution / query

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

So [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1190895) is my question on Mozilla support:

> So I am testing my website in the Responsive Design-modus and there is no problem with the the CSS. But when I am at my phone the site shows me the CSS of desktop. He zooms in because of the viewport (I think). I do not know if [this](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/web-pages-arent-displaying-properly-firefox-androi) is the problem.

What I tried with the CSS:

```
@media screen and (min-width: {PixelNumber}px) { /* CSS stuf */ } 
/*or*/ 
@media only screen and (min-width: {PixelNumber}px) { /* CSS stuf */ }
```

This is my html meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" property="viewport" content="width-device-width, initial-scale=0.9">
```

[Click here to view my site](http://rwalstijn.mtdef.com/)

On chrome: [image: chrome]
And on firefox [image: firefox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`width-device-width` in your viewport tag should be `width=device-width`